# Can I configure AC Power Restored option via iDRAC on a Dell PowerEdge server?

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

I'd like to configure the "AC Power Restored" option that's accessible in the BIOS, but I want to do it remotely, without having to shutdown the server and go into BIOS.

I've searched through the iDRAC 8 Enterprise interface and I can't find the option.

Am I seriously going to have to take the whole server down just to update this setting??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Twisty's solution is probably the easiest, it requires OMSA to be installed.

You actually can change this setting using the iDrac8, but from command line only.

To do so, SSH into the idrac (using `putty`or whatever your ssh client is). Then, enter those commands:

```
racadm set BIOS.SysSecurity.AcPwrRcvry Last # Possible values: On/Off/Last
racadm jobqueue create BIOS.Setup.1-1
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, except I've changed the AcPwrRcvry value to On, rather than Last.  Reason being, I believe APC PowerChute shuts down and switches off servers, so when the UPS charges up and switches back on, a server set to Last would remain off.  Great solution - I wouldn't have thought to use the iDRAC command line.  Wonder why the iDRAC web interface is missing this option?

Comment: Indeed, the idrac CLI is way more powerful than the GUI. Many racadm commands do not have a GUI equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this setting can be changed through the iDRAC.  However, according to this [Spiceworks thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/824676/can-i-configure-ac-power-restored-option-via-idrac-on-a-dell-poweredge-server) you can change the AC Power Recovery Mode option through Dell OpenManage Server Administrator:

> In OMSA you can select the "bios options" under the "main system Chassis". There you are able to change the "AC Power Recovery Mode"

Comment: We don't have OMSA installed on any of our servers.  If I did, this would have been the best solution to my problem.  I tried @sfk's solution, which worked perfectly without having to install additional software.